# Index usage, monitoring and dropping unused indexes - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a procedure that gathers index usage across a range of instances and databases, mainly using sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats. I am then going through indexes where the USER_UPDATES value is high and the USER_SEEKS, USER_SCANS, USER_LOOKUPS values are 0, indicating the index is not being used, and dropping them.

The problem I have is that the next time the procedure runs it does not reflect that the indexes have been dropped, as sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats only resets when the SQL Server service is restarted or the index is rebuilt.

I'd rather not have to rebuild the index before dropping it. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: you could join to `sys.indexes` to verify that index is present.

Comment: Try to recompile your SP otherwise they keep the old execution plan (at least at first run after indexes drops)

Comment: Joining with sys.indexes and checking `WHERE name IS NOT NULL` indeed worked and I had in fact already implemented this, there was simply a stupid error in my procedure elsewhere. Thanks everyone and sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining with sys.indexes and checking `WHERE name IS NOT NULL` indeed worked and I had in fact already implemented this, there was simply a stupid error in my procedure elsewhere. Thanks to Vladimir and everyone else and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to reset the DMV sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.

According to [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx),

> The counters are initialized to empty whenever the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is started. In addition, whenever a database is detached or is shut down (for example, because AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON), all rows associated with the database are removed.

The workaround would to use a persist the information in a user table with flag to mark when the index being dropped.
Next time when the SP is run, look at this user table and verify if the index is already dropped.

But do you need to do all this, I believe you will be using dynamic SQL to drop the indexes, wrap them with a IF EXISTS block could help you?

Comment: Thanks Satheesh. I was using SQL to drop the indexes, yes, but when my procedure was running to gather stats for monitoring, it was getting the old info.